# Error when trying to install python2 packages

Tags: apt, python, dpkg, dependencies

I'm on Kubuntu 19.10 and I've built python 3.8 from source and installed it using checkinstall. I then removed it and it somehow broke python 2.7. If I try installing any `python-*` package it produces an error like this one:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.17-1) but 3.8.1-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but that does nothing.

How do I fix this?

EDIT: `apt-cache policy python` output:

```
python:
  Installed: 3.8.1-1
  Candidate: 3.8.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.8.1-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.17-1 500
        500 http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Add the complete output of `apt-cache policy python` to your question above.

Comment: @user535733 Done. So it installed it under the same name apparently..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.8.1 was installed under the name python so what I did was run `sudo dpkg -r python` and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
ls -lh /usr/bin/python
```

to see if your default python version is 2.7. If not, see if you have the python 2.7 executable installed

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
```

Make your /usr/bin/python link points to the right python version

```
rm /usr/bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 python
```

Fianlly, make sure you have a link to the python2.7 config file in /usr/bin/. For example, I have /usr/bin/python2-config pointing to python2.7-config

Answer (score 0):

When you built your package, looks like you called it 'python' instead of 'python3.8'.

That was unwise. Now the system expects 'python' to be version 3.8 instead of 2.7.

How to fix it **if you have lots of Python2 packages that you don't want to reinstall**:

- Budget plenty of time to do this. DO NOT RUSH.
- Read your output carefully. If you encounter an error at any step, STOP immediately. Do NOT proceed.
- This will work on my system. We don't know what changes you have made to yours.

1) Make a complete backup of all your data and a working LiveUSB on-hand. You are going to be using very strong medicine. The patient may have unexpected complications.

2) Ensure all traces of the built Python 3.8 package are removed.

3) Remove the all files installed by the `python` package while leaving the rest of your Python2.7 packages in place.

```
 sudo dpkg remove python --force-depends
 // 'python' places no files in /etc, so 'remove' is appropriate.
```

4) Drop all traces of the `python` package from your apt/dpkg database.
 **WARNING**: If improperly used, this command may ruin your system.

```
 sudo dpkg remove python --force-depends --force-remove-reinstreq
```

5) Reinstall the correct `python` package:

```
 sudo apt install python
```